# How can I customize keyboard shortcuts in Thunderbird?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, thunderbird

I would love to get hjkl movement and some other vim-like keybindings, like / for search, if possible. I'm aware of Dactyl's thunderbird project, but it looks like it's in alpha. Similarly, Mutterator looks like it's not being actively developed anymore, and doesn't work with Thunderbird 7, which is what I use. If I could easily edit thunderbird's keybindings i think I could just do this sort of thing for myself.

I'm running Ubuntu 11.10, by the way.

Comment: Duplicate: [Disable keyboard shortcuts in Thunderbird](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/141523)

Comment: related bugreport: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=615957

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Keyconfig](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?t=72994) allows you to configure keyboard shortcuts.

Read more about it [here](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Keyconfig_extension).

Comment: To install you have to right-click on the first word in the old first forum post "keyconfig" in the [linked forum](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=48&t=72994) from "April 30th, 2004" and install the .xpi file in thunderbirds add-ons "as file"

Comment: As keyconfig/Dorando keyconfig no longer works with Thunderbird 68 (and the maintainer does not currently plan to update it, see https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/dorando-keyconfig/) this question has renewed urgency. If anyone has pointers on how to make even simple keyboard rebindings in Thunderbird 68, such as deleting messages with backspace rather than delete, please post here. Thanks!

Comment: Should no longer be the accepted answer. The first link is dead, the second does lead to a page, leading to the extension addon listing, which is unmaintained and only works for Thunderbird 5.0b1 - 60.* (current is 115.6.1). @Jonathan - can you select a new accepted answer?

Answer (score 19):

**Update 07/2020:** Your best bet for custom keybindings currently seems to be: [tbkeys](https://github.com/willsALMANJ/tbkeys). Follow the instructions there to get keybindings, customizable within a file in your user-home directory (see [here](https://hg.mozilla.org/comm-central/file/tip/mail/base/content/mainCommandSet.inc.xhtml) for cmd references [PR created to include in README.MD]).

**Update 12/2019:** As of Thunderbird 68 dorando is currently not supported anymore. A good (deep dive) source of current development can be found in the [mozilla forums](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=48&t=72994&start=3435) or directly at the [github of the dorando project](https://github.com/trlkly/dorando-keyconfig/issues).

**OP:**

Seems like the original keyconfig from 14 years ago is not compatible anymore with thunderbird 60.0 and up.

[dorando-keyconfig](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/dorando-keyconfig) is the official new supported version as far as i can tell.
Some descriptions seem to be missing, but not a big issue (i.e. "Mark > As Read" is key_toggleRead).

Thanks to dorando and the new maintainers for keeping up the good work .

Comment: Thanks. This is the addon that works now. I can get by with it simulating Vim keybindings even without Muttator.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Now I can finally get rid of the ill-advised single-letter shortcuts in Thunderbird. With Thunderbird's years-long issue of randomly re-routing keyboard input to the main window, this has been causing mayhem for me when typing emails.

Comment: It seems with Thunderbird 68, even dorando-keyconfig does not work anymore.

Comment: @hibbelig - yes i can confirm the problem. Guess it's time to hunt for another replacement again :(

Answer (score 6):

The add-on [tbkeys](https://github.com/willsALMANJ/tbkeys) can do this for you.

To install this, follow the [Readme](https://github.com/willsALMANJ/tbkeys#install)

---

For older Thunderbird versions:

The old [keyconfig Add-On](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=48&t=72994) could do this up to Thunderbird 67:

To install this, you have to

- **right-click** on the first word **"keyconfig"** [in the old first forum post here](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=48&t=72994) from "April 30th, 2004"
- install the [keyconfig.xpi](http://mozilla.dorando.at/keyconfig.xpi) file in thunderbirds add-ons "as file"
- open the settings for the extension **"keyconfig 20110522"**, there you can configure all key-shortcuts you like

Answer (score 5):

You can unzip Thunderbird's chrome and edit the .dtd files within them, which usually contain the key bindings, if you want something that's not extension-dependent. Here's an example from a DTD file for my extension:

```
<!ENTITY removedupes.remove_duplicates_menuitems.remove.accesskey "D">
<!ENTITY removedupes.remove_duplicates_menuitems.set_originals.accesskey "o">
<!ENTITY key-removedupes.modifiers "alt,shift">
```

this is of course much less convenient than using [KeyConfig](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?t=72994), but that's the low-level non-dynamic way to do it.

Comment: which `chrome.jar` file do you refer to? I couldn't find any on my linux system

Comment: @rubo77: Ok, doesn't necessarily have to be a JAR. Example: http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/thunderbird/releases/latest/win32/xpi/en-US.xpi has a bunch of dtd's

Comment: So what is your suggestion? KeyConfig is not available any more for Thunderbird 31 so how can I customize my shortcuts? can You add an example how to disable the "j" shortcut for junk for example?

Comment: Similar to https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/563600/19012 which says they're inside omni.ja?

Comment: @einpoklum: your link doesn't work any more, Is this still working in TB 68?

Answer (score 2):

[tbkeys](https://github.com/willsALMANJ/tbkeys) offers also [tbkeys-lite](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/tbkeys-lite/) `Add-on`, which sets these default `Main key bindings`:

```
{
    "j": "cmd:cmd_nextMsg",
    "k": "cmd:cmd_previousMsg",
    "o": "cmd:cmd_openMessage",
    "f": "cmd:cmd_forward",
    "#": "cmd:cmd_delete",
    "r": "cmd:cmd_reply",
    "a": "cmd:cmd_replyall",
    "x": "cmd:cmd_archive",
    "c": "func:MsgNewMessage",
    "u": "tbkeys:closeMessageAndRefresh"
}
```

Works a treat in `Thunderbird v68.12.0` for my vimified fingers!

Answer (score 1):

The addon [MenuWizard](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/s3menu-wizard/) allows you to configure plenty of keyboard shortcuts for Thunderbird. For basic vim/gmail-like bindings, you can set `j`, `k`, `o`, and `e` (or `y`) to `key_nextUnreadMsg`, `key_previousUnreadMsg`, `key_OpenMessage`, and `key_archive`, respectively.

Unfortunately, you cannot search among the shortcuts in Menuwizard so you have to scroll around and look for the relevant key. The `key_<name>` is more informative than the name next to the checkbox.